# How to create an ASP.NET Core API controller action for HttpPost that can accept a request that has content of type MultipartFormDataContent

Tags: asp.net-core, http-post, multipartform-data, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 2.0 API in VS2017.

I want to create a controller action for an HTTP Post method that accept string and byte[] values that I will then use to create records in my SQL database.

From what I understand, if I want to post both string data and a byte[] that represents a file, I have to use MultipartFormDataContent as the type of content in the request from my client.

So, on the API controller action, how is that mapped? Can I have a DTO class in the API that has properties for both the string values and the byte[] value and have it passed into the API controller action via the [FromBody]UploadsDto dto

For example, have a DTO class like this...

```
public class UploadFileRecordForCreationDto
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] UploadedFile { get; set; }
}
```

Then have a controller action with this signature...

```
[HttpPost(Name = "CreateUploadFileRecord")]
public IActionResult CreateUploadFileRecord([FromBody]UploadFileRecordForCreationDto dto)
{
    ...
    ...
    ...

    return CreatedAtRoute("GetUploadedFileFile", new { id = linkedResourceToReturn["Id"] }, linkedResourceToReturn);

}
```

And then have that API action accept a request created using something similar to what I am doing with this test console application on the client side;

```
    static async Task CreateUploadFileRecordAsync()
    {

        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44369");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        string relativeUrl = "/api/UploadFilesManager";

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, relativeUrl);

        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent("--UploadTest"))
        {
            var values = new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("LocationId","1"),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("FileName","TestFile-01.txt"),
            };

            foreach (var keyvaluepair in values)
            {
                content.Add(new StringContent(keyvaluepair.Value, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"), keyvaluepair.Key);
            }

            var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\testfile-01.txt"));
            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue(DispositionTypeNames.Attachment)
            {
                Name = "UploadedFile",
                FileName = "testfile-01.txt"
            };
            content.Add(fileContent);
            request.Content = content;

            response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        }


        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string result = response.Headers.Location.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Success:\n");
            Console.WriteLine($"New Record Link: [{result}]\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to create new UploadFile record. Error:  {0}\n", response.ReasonPhrase);
        }

    }
```

If it doesn't just map to a DTO in the FromBody, can anyone provide an example of how to deal with this use case?

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result?

Comment: Try the FromForm attribute.

Comment: @Tratcher I tested a controller action using a dto object and even changed signature from "FromBody" to "FromForm" as you suggested. The string values are passing through but the binary array (file) is null. There must be a different way of handling multipart that perhaps sees the binary file as an attachment somehow? The part in the client code that adds the binary array to the request has this line...

fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue(DispositionTypeNames.Attachment)

Comment: Yeah, it likely ends up in the Request.Form.Files collection. You could skip the model binding for that one and access it directly.

Comment: No joy. The Request.Form.Files is empty.